# how to read value in structure

Tags: c, linux

I'm reading file using fread().[read file only]
On compilation, the compiler throws a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.
I'm using structure.

I wrote this code.

```
type #include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>


int twilio_send_functionapi(char *channel, char *status); // function declartion 

struct credentials
 {

 char *account_sid;
 char *auth_token;
 char *from_number;
 char *to_number;

 } c1;
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   

    FILE *fp;
    struct credentials input;
    fp = fopen("data.config", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    dentials.to_number = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    while(fread(&c1,sizeof(struct credentials),1 ,fp))
    fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %s", c1.account_sid, c1.auth_token,c1.from_number, c1.to_number);   
    
    char *channel,*status;

    channel = argv[1];
    status =  argv[2];
    twilio_send_functionapi(channel,status); //function call

}
```

Don't know where I'm mistaken.
here is .conf file which needs to be read

> ```
> account_sid : AC40cfb4f3e98b55b13a9b93527683171e
> auth_token  : 5f6906d7847ad1fc1fc1170ab60e40fd
> from_number : 15867854760
> to_number   : 1212321123
> ```

Comment: Hint: where are the pointers in the struct pointing to?

Comment: Do you know what fread does?

Comment: The `fread` instructs that the four binary pointer members are read from file, and then presumes that text follows, with textual values to scan into where they point. And then you repeat it. It 99% unlikely that you can read valid pointers from a file, or that a file would be structured like this.

Comment: You can't do this with an `fscanf` as you have it. And, even less so with `fread`. Each line is a "key/value" pair of the form: `key : value`. Do `fgets`. Then, use `strtok` or `strchr` to find/split on the `:`. Then, remove leading/trailing whitespace on the [now separate] key and value pairs. Either use a loop on a table of key strings, or use separate `strcmp` calls to decide which key to store (e.g.): `if (strcmp(key,"account_sid") == 0) c1.account_sid = strdup(value);` Is there only _one_ record in the file (with 4 "fields")? Or, do you need to loop and have an array of your structs?

Comment: The structure should contain character arrays, not pointers. Or you need to use `malloc()` to allocate memory for each of the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `fread()`, `fscanf()`, use `fgets()` to read a  line of the file into a *string*.

```
//               123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 
//account_sid :  AC40cfb4f3e98b55b13a9b93527683171e

#define SID_LEN 34

struct credentials {
  char account_sid[SID_LEN + 1];  // Use array here, not pointer.
  // ... omitted for  brevity
 } c1;

#define LINE_SIZE 100
char line[LINE_SIZE];
if (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {
  if (sscanf(line, "account_sid : %34s", c1.account_sid) == 1) {
    ; // Success
  } else {
    ; // Failed
  }
```

Continue likewise for the other `c1` members`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.
I resolve my problem.

```
char credential[4][100] ;
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
     fp = fopen("data.config", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("Error\n");
    return -1;
}
printf("File is opened\n"); 
     if ((fscanf(fp,"account_sid-%s\n",credential[0])!= 1))
     {
     printf("error reading account_sid value\n");
     return -1;
     }
     fclose(fp);
      }
```